# How to add Suggestion Chips through Fulfillment for the Dialogflow Messenger integration?

Tags: dialogflow-es, embed, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

So I have the Dialogflow Messenger embedded in a website and want to add some Suggestion chips. It's easy through the *Custom Payload* Response type and they show up just fine.
But how do I add them through fulfillment?

I currently have a custom webhook setup and the idea is to have something like this:

```
if (x) {
  agent.add('blablabla');
  agent.add(new Suggestion('One');
} else {
  agent.add('blablabla');
  agent.add(new Suggestion('Two');
}
```

*new Suggestion* doesn't work though, so is there another way of doing this?
I was thinking about something like this:

```
agent.add(new Payload(
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "One"
          },
          {
            "text": "Two"
          }
        ],
        "type": "chips"
      }
    ]
  ]));
```

Essentially trying to insert the Custom Payload directly into the response JSON, if that makes any sense. But yeah no idea how to actually do it. Anyone know how?

Comment: There is another question that solve same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635831/how-to-use-rich-response-messages-like-suggestion-chips-on-dialogflow-messenger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you exactly mean by *new Suggestion() doesn't work*. You mean the suggestion chips do not show in Dialogflow Messenger? Do they show in Dialogflow itself?

Let me share a few points:

- As far as I know the structure `agent.add(new Suggestion(“One”));` should work. I tried a simple example and it is working fine in Dialogflow UI, with the code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  function welcome(agent){ 
    agent.add("What is your favorite animal?");
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Dog"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Cat"));
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

- If suggestions chips are not rendered even in Dialogflow UI I would suggest trying the previous code to discard any potential issues with your Dialogflow setup. You may need to upgrade some dependencies e.g. `"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"`.
- Some integrations, like Google Assistant use the `Suggestions` library from `actions-on-google`. See for example [official Google Assistant code example](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#SuggestionChipsSamples). You may try to follow a similar behavior if it fits your use case although I do not think it is the case. As a reference you can check [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/100) github issue.

Comment: "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1".
This worked for me. Thanks